# How does this Roman to Number function work? (reduce, lambda)

Tags: python

This function converts string roman numerals into integers by iterating from the right and adding to the symbol on the left unless it is greater, then it subtracts. What I don't understand is how `i` gets assigned to a index in the string. How does it bind to the iterator from `range` when it reduces?

```
import functools

def roman_to_integer(s):
    T = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
    return functools.reduce(lambda val, i: val + (-T[s[i]] if T[s[i]] < T[s[i + 1]] else T[s[i]]), reversed(range(len(s) - 1)), T[s[-1]])
```

I know this is very un-Pythonic. I found this example in a book on interview questions in Python and want to understand why this works.

Comment: Let's get this straight: this is NOT how you should be writing code in python.

Comment: The second argument to `reduce` is an element from the list `reversed(range(len(s) - 1))`

Answer (score 1):

[`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) is - in simplified terms- a simple, anonymous function. You can break it up just like a function based on the colon:

```
f = lambda x,*args,k = 5, **kw: print(x,args,k,kw)

def f (x, *args, k = 5, **kw): return print(x,args,k,kw)
```

The string `s` and the dictionary `T` are available in a [scope](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) higher than the `lambda` and neither is assigned within the `lambda` statement, so the `lambda` has access to both.

[`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) is a function that basically maps another callable across an iterable. As you can see in the docs, `reduce` applies the current result as the first argument to the given callable, and the current item as the second argument. A third argument can be supplied to reduce, which is the starting value; if not supplied, the first element in iterable will be used instead.

```
## This is just an example, obviously...
import functools, operator
functools.reduce(operator.add,range(4))
## Step 0: No default, so first element of range is used as the current value: 0
## Step 1: add(0,next(range)) => add(0,1) => 1
## Step 2: add(1,next(range)) => add(1,2) => 3
## Step 3: add(3,next(range)) => add(3,3) => 6
## Step 4: No more items in range, so return current value: 6
```

So, as you can see, the current element of `range` (the iterable passed to `reduce`) is passed at each Step as the second argument (`i`) to the function passed to `reduce` (`lambda`). The `lambda` function then uses the second argument (`i`) to index string `s`